# Plot frequency table of vector in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have created a frequency of the values of a vector with the `table` function and plotted the distribution (over a length of 10).

```
x <- c(1,3,5,5,6)

plot(table(x), type = "p", pch = 20, xlim = c(1, 10), axes = FALSE)
axis(side = 1, at = c(seq(0, 10, by = 1)))
axis(side = 2)
```

How can I make this plot with ggplot?

If I create a data frame from the `table` function, the x axis is not scaled properly (instead the values on the x axis are categorical).

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(as.data.frame(table(x)), aes(x, Freq)) +
  geom_point()
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: You can use `as.numeric(x)` rather than `x` in the aes, and the scale will be continuous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`table(x)` returns x as a `factor`, you will have to cast it back to numeric for the scale to be continuous.

```
ggplot(as.data.frame(table(x))) + 
    geom_point(aes(x = as.numeric(as.character(x)), 
                   y = Freq)) + 
    scale_x_continuous()
```

Or you can  let `ggplot2` do the calculation for you:

```
ggplot(as.data.frame(x)) +
    geom_point(aes(x = x), stat = 'count')
```

[image]